# How thick should my tile underlayment be?

Tags: tile, underlayment

Am remodeling, and installing tile floor. Joists are 2x8 16 o.c., subfloor is 5/8 plywood perpendicular to joists, for underlayment should I use 3/8 plywood+1/2 in. backerboard or 5/8 ply+1/4 in. b-board? (also, should underlayment be laid same direction as subfloor? (with offset seams) thanks, Ray

Comment: What kind of tile?

Comment: Porcelain, 6x36.

Comment: First thing to check out is this: https://www.johnbridge.com/vbulletin/deflecto.pl

Comment: Came up just short of specs for tile, wonder if blocking would work?

Comment: Blocking is only useful to support seams in subfloor, as far as I know, but I'm not an expert. I would consider doing at least a partial-sister on the joists to strengthen them, if you're not able to do a full sister

Comment: Yeah...not sure about that, but know someone who does, think I better consult him before I go any farther. Thanks Joe, especially for the deflection table, didnt know such a tool existed.

Comment: Good luck. Normally porcelain wouldn't be an issue but since yours is 36" long, definitely worth spending a bit more time ensuring it won't snap in half!

Comment: Some tile manufacturers will give recommendations on the underlayment.  You may want to check the box or the company's website.

Answer (score 1):

When I did this in my old house I had a 3/4" subfloor and used 1/4" backer board (with 1/4" notch thinset between the subfloor and backer). I don't think that direction matters given how many fasteners you'll use on that backer board. Don't neglect to tape the joints either.

That floor never moved after adding tile on top.

Comment: Ok thanks, sounds like its just getting the same base 2 different ways, and either way it should be adequate. Thanks for reply